# UIButton properties for UIBarButtonSystemItemDone

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I want to create a `UIButton` same like `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone`.

That is, my UIButton should looks like the following image

[image]

Can i make the same effects (rounded corner, shading of colors, size) on my UIButton?

Share your code please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom button and provide an image for it.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:urImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Yes you can but you need an image first that is similar to the bar button item. So design the image first and add the image to your app bundle

Comment: Without an image, is it possible to create those effects on the UIButton?